# submitting EditForm via @onkeydown does not clear TextInputArea in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

this is my EditForm:

```
<div class="edit-form">
    <EditForm Model="Message" OnValidSubmit="SendRequest" OnInvalidSubmit="Invalid" @onkeyup="@Enter" class="edit-form">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <p><InputTextArea style="background-color:#4d4d4d;color:#cb8c04;font-weight:bold;" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Zadaj pytanie" @bind-Value="@Message"></InputTextArea></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;"class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="NewChat" type="button">New chat</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</EditForm>
</div>
```

this is code behind:

```
    private async Task SendRequest()
    {
        //something
    }

    private async Task Invalid()
    {

    }
    #region TechnicalMethodsForBetterUsage
    private async Task Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" && !e.ShiftKey)
        {
            await SendRequest();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

and here is a thing:

if i send request via button InputTextArea clear state and it is empty. But if i send request via keystroke Enter it stays. How i can make it clear? Enter = Send button.

Comment: If your model is resetting on a submit then there's code you aren't showing.  And if you hit enter in a `TextArea`, it should give you a new line.  Calling `Enter` directly also bypasses validation.  you can't run validation in one path and not in the other.  Please provide a [mre] 
 i.e. working example to demonstrate your problem

Comment: i provided you with my code, what you need more from me? @MrCakaShaunCurtis if you are c# dev this is understandable for you.

Comment: [Polite]  You provided us with some of your code, judging what was relevant and not relevant. "if i send request via button InputTextArea clear state and it is empty".  That's not normal behaviour and there's nothing in your code that will do that. Therefore `//something` does that.   You have a NewChat button with a method you haven't shown that would do that. PS - Check my profile and previous answers to see if I'm a C# dev qualified to answer your question..

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis New Chat button is not something that is relevant to my question. You have all infromation provided.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  this button:                     <button style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button> submit EditForm and it passess value to Message and it is ok. Enter method does not. this is the case.

Comment: In that case I'll leave someone else to answer it for you.  This is not a consulting service, People help you out of good will.

Comment: first off all you are using a Model="Message" and binding the input to the message with: @bind-Value="@Message", this cannot be correct. Message should be a class not a string for the model validation. However after that is fixed the problem here is that the InputTextArea creates a new line when pressing enter. You have to prevent that somehow. In order for you method to work, assuming you setting the string to string.empty in the SendRequest method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jeb i fixed that and forget to mention here. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer.

As @Jeb said. Model cannot be the same as bind-Value and this was my problem. This is how i fixed that:

```
 <div class="edit-form">
    <EditForm id="editForm" Model="@Message" OnValidSubmit="SendRequest" OnInvalidSubmit="Invalid" class="edit-form">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <p>
            <InputTextArea 
                @onkeyup="Enter"
                @oninput="Input"
                           @bind-Value="message"
                style="background-color:#444654;color:#dcce85;font-weight:bold;" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Ask question" 
               >
            </InputTextArea>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn form-button" type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn form-button" @onclick="Resend" type="button">Resend</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn form-button" @onclick="NewChat" type="button">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>
    #region TechnicalMethodsForBetterUsage
    public async Task Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Key == "Enter" && !e.ShiftKey)
        {
            await  SendRequest();
        }
    }
    public async Task Input(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        message = e.Value.ToString();

    }

    #endregion
```

I changed bind-value from Message (model) to variable message and this does work.